# CentOs 7, "Tesseract couldn't load any languages!" however: "List of available languages (2): eng, spa"

Tags: tesseract

this is CentOs 7

when I run `tesseract --list-langs`

```
[root@cia tessdata]# tesseract --list-langs
Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
List of available languages (2):
eng
spa
[root@cia tessdata]#
```

however when I run

```
[root@cia tessdata]# ls -l /usr/local/share/tessdata/
total 328
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Nov 17 23:28 configs
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 164228 Nov 18 06:11 eng.traineddata
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    572 Nov 17 23:28 pdf.ttf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 157745 Nov 18 06:11 spa.traineddata
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     98 Nov 17 23:28 tessconfigs
[root@cia tessdata]#
```

I get `eng.traineddata` and `spa.traineddata` in this form:

```
cd /usr/local/share/tessdata
wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/main/eng.traineddata
wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/main/spa.traineddata
```

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

allways I install languages with:

```
wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata
wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/spa.traineddata
```

then allways tesseract work fine, but now this return 404

how I can fix?

Comment: Did you check your link: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata? It does not exist. The correct link is https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/eng.traineddata

Comment: MANY thanks master @user898678,
your comment/URL (answer) is 100% PERFECT. Please rewrite as ANSWER for I vote as answer POSITIVE. How you find this URL? where is the instructions for arrive to this?